# How to convert ifnull statement in tableau to powerbi dax?

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, tableau-api, dax, ifnull

I'm working on a dashboard conversion from tableau to power bi.Stuck with a calculated dimension in tableau that is needed to be converted to powerbi using dax!

By Replacing the IFNULL statement in tableau. I've tried the ISBLANK parameter in dax with an IF statement that should check if the field returns a null value or not. My knowledge on dax is limited, I suppose this problem is really simple but I'm stuck with this for quite hours.

tableau code that is need to be converted to powerbi:

```
if LEFT([Supplier Code],1) = "E" then "Employees Claims" else 
IF 
IFNULL(IFNULL([ASL Supplier (SWPS)],IFNULL([Supplier Name],IFNULL([Vendor],[Supplier Code]))),'Not Define')= 'N/A'
THEN IFNULL([Vendor],[Supplier Name]) ELSE
IFNULL(IFNULL([ASL Supplier (SWPS)],IFNULL([Supplier Name],IFNULL([Vendor],[Supplier Code]))),'Not Define') 
END
END
```

Power bi code which i've tried:

```
Supplier (swps) = IF(LEFT([Supplier Code],1) = "E", "Employee Claims",
IF(
IF(ISBLANK(V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[ASL Supplier (SWPS)]),ISBLANK(V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[Supplier Name]),ISBLANK(V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[Supplier Code])),"Not Define") = "N/A")
```

My code is incomplete as i'm not able to understand the complete break down of the code in tableau.

tableau :

```
if LEFT([Supplier Code],1) = "E" then "Employees Claims" else 
IF 
IFNULL(IFNULL([ASL Supplier (SWPS)],IFNULL([Supplier Name],IFNULL([Vendor],[Supplier Code]))),'Not Define')= 'N/A'
THEN IFNULL([Vendor],[Supplier Name]) ELSE
IFNULL(IFNULL([ASL Supplier (SWPS)],IFNULL([Supplier Name],IFNULL([Vendor],[Supplier Code]))),'Not Define') 
END
END
```

Expected result is a dimension/column that has the values as the given condition in power bi.

Comment: I think you will achieve your goal easier and faster if instead of trying to convert Tableau to DAX you just provide a data sample, describe your data model and the desired outcome. It's much easier to solve such problems from scratch rather than dealing with the conversion complexities.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, I find it most useful to break down the original logic of the Tableau code:

- If Supplier Code starts with "E", then "Employee Claims"
- Else,

  - Checking in order, if ASL Supplier (SWPS), Supplier Name, Vendor, Supplier Code = "N/A", then

    - If Vendor is not null, then Vendor
    - Else, Supplier Name
  - Else, checking in order,

    - if ASL Supplier (SWPS), Supplier Name, Vendor, Supplier Code has a value, use it
    - Else, use "Not Define"

Given this, the DAX formula would be:

```
Supplier (swps) =
VAR vendorOrSupplier =
    IF (
        ISBLANK ( V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[Vendor] ),
        V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[Supplier Name],
        V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[Vendor]
    )
VAR firstValidField =
    IF (
        ISBLANK ( V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[ASL Supplier (SWPS)] ),
        IF (
            ISBLANK ( V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[Supplier Name] ),
            IF (
                ISBLANK ( V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[Vendor] ),
                IF (
                    ISBLANK ( V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[Supplier Code] ),
                    "Not Defined",
                    V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[Supplier Code]
                ),
                V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[Vendor]
            ),
            V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[Supplier Name]
        ),
        V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[ASL Supplier (SWPS)]
    )
VAR allBlank =
    IF ( firstValidField = "Not Defined", TRUE (), FALSE () )
RETURN
    IF (
        LEFT ( V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[Supplier Code], 1 ) = "E",
        "Employee Claims",
        IF (
            V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[ASL Supplier (SWPS)] = "N/A",
            vendorOrSupplier,
            IF (
                ISBLANK ( V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[ASL Supplier (SWPS)] ),
                IF (
                    V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[Supplier Name] = "N/A",
                    vendorOrSupplier,
                    IF (
                        ISBLANK ( V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[Supplier Name] ),
                        IF (
                            V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[Vendor] = "N/A",
                            vendorOrSupplier,
                            IF (
                                ISBLANK ( V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[Vendor] ),
                                IF ( [Supplier Code] = "N/A", vendorOrSupplier, firstValidField ),
                                firstValidField
                            )
                        ),
                        firstValidField
                    )
                ),
                firstValidField
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: Tableau Logic : Below the column supplier (swps), supplier swps , vendor, suppliercode are checked if they are equal to = "N/A" then Supplier(swps) is returned. if not the they should return the same values? 
The Powerbi code i generated for creating this column is also mentioned below. Can you validate it if its correct? I'm getting the column generated but feel if i made a mistake!

Comment: Nafih, you may want to try your formula in one column and mine in another to help you validate.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF IFNULL([ASL Supplier(SWPS)],IFNULL([Supplier(SWPS)],IFNULL([Vendor],IFNULL([Supplier Code],'Not Define')))) = 'N/A'
THEN [Supplier(SWPS)] 
ELSE IFNULL([ASL Supplier (SWPS)],IFNULL([Supplier(SWPS)],IFNULL([Vendor],IFNULL([Supplier Code],'Not Define'))))
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
supplier = var supplierswps = 
 `IF (
                              ISBLANK (V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[ASL Supplier(SWPS)]),
        IF (
             ISBLANK (V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne [Supplier (SWPS)]),
            IF (
                ISBLANK ( V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[Vendor] ),
                IF (
                    ISBLANK (V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne [Supplier Code]),"Not Define")))= "N/A",V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[Supplier (swps)])
var supplierswpsfalse = IF(supplierswps = "Not define", TRUE(), FALSE())
        return
            if( 
               ISBLANK(V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[ASL Supplier (SWPS)] ),
                IF (
                    ISBLANK (V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[Supplier (SWPS)]),
                     IF(
                        ISBLANK ( V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[Vendor] ),
                            IF (
                                ISBLANK (V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[Supplier Code] )
                            ,"Not Define",
                            V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[Supplier Code]
                                ),
`

                       V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[Vendor]  

                     ),V_FIPnLDashboard_Tne[Supplier (SWPS)]
                ),V_FIPnLDashboard_TnE[ASL Supplier (SWPS)]
            )
```